# How do I set Discord's Birthdate using Selenium

Tags: node.js, selenium

I'm trying to set a birthdate on the Discord Register page using Selenium, but I am not exactly sure how. I also tried searching online how to set a birthdate similarly to how Discord does it, but can't find any.

[Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1TTM.png)

Comment: Please add some code to your question to show what you've already tried and specify where exactly you have a problem - what is not working for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, nvm. Part of the code of how I did it.

```js
              let findmonthButton = tab.findElement(swd.By.className("month-1Z2bRu"));
              return findmonthButton;
            })
            .then(function(findmonthButton) {
              let promiseMonthButton = findmonthButton.click();
              return promiseMonthButton
            })
            .then(function() {
              console.log("Month clicked successfully");
            
              let findmonth = tab.findElement(swd.By.className("css-rzbxvl-option"));
              return findmonth;
            })
            .then(function(findmonth) {
              let promiseMouth = findmonth.click();
              return promiseMouth
            })
            .then(function() {
              console.log("January clicked successfully");

             let findDayButton = tab.findElement(swd.By.className("day-1uOKpp"));
              return findDayButton;
            })
            .then(function(findDayButton) {
              let promiseDayButton = findDayButton.click();
              return promiseDayButton;
            })
            .then(function() {
              console.log("Day clicked successfully");

              let findDay = tab.findElement(swd.By.className("css-1yz4bi9-option"));
              return findDay;
            })
            .then(function(findDay) {
              let promiseDay = findDay.click();
              return promiseDay;
            })
            .then(function() {
              console.log("Day clicked successfully");

              let findYearButton = tab.findElement(swd.By.className("year-3_SRuv"));
              return findYearButton;
            })
            .then(function(findYearButton) {
              let promiseYearButton = findYearButton.click();
              return promiseYearButton;
            })
            .then(function() {
              console.log("Year clicked successfully");

              let findYear = tab.findElement(swd.By.xpath("//div[text()='1997']"))
              return findYear;
            })
            .then(function(findYear) {
              let promiseYear = findYear.click();
              return promiseYear;
            })
            .then(function() {
              console.log("a Year clicked successfully");

             let promiseSignInBtn = tab.findElement(swd.By.className("button-1cRKG6 button-f2h6uQ lookFilled-yCfaCM colorBrand-I6CyqQ sizeLarge-3mScP9 fullWidth-fJIsjq grow-2sR_-F"));
             return promiseSignInBtn;
            })
              
            .then(function (signInBtn) {
              // Step 7 - Clicking the Sign In button
              let promiseClickSignIn = signInBtn.click();
              return promiseClickSignIn;
            })
```